# Pass a SQL query result into multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a datagrid that is populated by a SQL server. I am trying to select a row from the list of entries and enter them into textboxes outside the grid. I can't seem to find a way to convert the query result into manageable data, other than to populate the grid.

C#

```
MoviesEntities dataEntities = new MoviesEntities();
ObjectQuery<MovieTable> _movies = dataEntities.MovieTables;

var query =
    from MovieTable in _movies
    where MovieTable.Title == MMEM.MovieTitle
    select MovieTable.id;
    string result = Convert.ToString(query); //or something??
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MovieApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="650" 
    Width="525"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MovieApp">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MovieAppViewModel x:Key="MovieAppViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel x:Name="RootStackPanel" DataContext="{StaticResource MovieAppViewModel}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="99" Width="440">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Movie Title" Margin="30 0 30 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Heavy"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Rating" Margin="30 0 30 0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Heavy"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Stars" Margin="30 0 30 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Heavy"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Release Year"  Margin="30 0 30 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Heavy"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MMEM.MovieTitle}"  IsEnabled="{Binding MMEM.IsEditable}" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="50" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MMEM.Rating}"  IsEnabled="{Binding MMEM.IsEditable}" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="5" Width="55"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MMEM.Stars}"  IsEnabled="{Binding MMEM.IsEditable}" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="5" Width="20"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MMEM.ReleaseYear}"  IsEnabled="{Binding MMEM.IsEditable}" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="20" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Edit Mode" Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid 
        Width="Auto" 
        SelectionMode="Extended" 
        IsReadOnly="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MMLM.MoviesList}"
        DataContext="{StaticResource MovieAppViewModel}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Rating" Binding="{Binding Rating}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="Stars" Binding="{Binding Stars}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="93" Header="Release Year" Binding="{Binding ReleaseYear}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

I am under the assumption that there is a more efficient way than parsing the row into strings and populating the textboxes, but at this point I'll take what I can get!

Thanks for any input!!!!

Comment: Post your XAML - both the grid and the textboxes code. You should be able to bind your grid to the data source and get it to populate (semi)-automatically.

Comment: The grid is populating automatically, but I want to get the data from a selected row into the TextBoxes above. Not sure if that's what you meant, but yeah I've got that part down. Thanks for input

Comment: You should be able to get the selected row from the grid (I do Silverlight so I'm not up to speed with the exact syntax for WPF) which will give you an object - MovieEntity? in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just name thedatagrid eg  masterDG

Then in the detail

```
 Binding ElementName=masterDG, path=SelecedItem.Title
```